# Выполнение команд во вложенных панелях

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Есть `ItemsControl`, к которому забиндили `ObservableCollection` обьектов.

Кнопки, которые появились в этом `ItemsControl`, не выполняют прибинженные к ним комманды. Проблем с командами нет, так как, если просто прибиндить команду к кнопке то команда выполняется. А в `ItemsControl` уже нет

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Seats}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding SeatName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ChangeStatus} />
        </DataTemplate>                
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Класс обьекта Seat

```
 public class Seat
    {  
        public int SeatId { get; set; }
        public string SeatName { get; set; }     
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public int SectorId { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get;set; }
        public virtual Row Row { get; set; }
    }
```

Код команды

```
 public RelayCommand _changeStatus;
        public ICommand ChangeStatus
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changeStatus == null)
                    _changeStatus = new RelayCommand(Execute, CanExecute);
                return _changeStatus;
            }
        }

        void Execute(object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Команда выполняется");
        }
        bool CanExecute(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: «так как если просто сделать ... то все работает» — что означает «всё работает»?

Comment: А где собственно бинд команд? Я может что-то путаю, но Content батонов не для команд.

Comment: Кстати: `Margin="405,160,0,0"` — ужасно. Почитайте про layout management.

Comment: извеняюсь,поправил описание.

Comment: А покажите код объекта, коллекцию которых вы биндите.

Comment: т.е. SeatName в Content кнопки выставляется как надо, а вот команда ChangeStatus не вызывается?

Comment: ixSci - да,именно

Comment: В каком классе объявлена команда `ChangeStatus`? В том же, что и коллекция `Seats`? Дайте его полный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас же нет свойства команды `ChangeStatus` в объекте `Seat`. Если запустите приложение и внимательно посмотрите в окошко Output, то увидите там запись о том, что привязка не удалась, т.к. свойство не было найдено.

Comment: Команда отдельно объявлена

Comment: @grayraw согласно вашей разметке, она должна находиться в `Seat`. Где именно она объявлена? Не цедите по чайной ложке, дайте полную информацию :).

Comment: Да,полностью правы,я осознал что делал не так